# Is it Possible for a Biological Creature to Spew/Breathe an Explosive Instead?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, xenobiology, explosions

I want to make my dragon spew/breathe an explosive mix with gizzard stone fragments/shrapnel, more like a shotgun than the common flamethrower-like fire breath.

So is there any explosive chemical that can be reproduced biologically and be safely contained in the creature's internal organs? (I mean something like a gunpowder explosion not a hot water jet like a bombardier beetle or from pure pressure or muscle contractions, although I don't want to exclude a liquid type of explosion.) If possible include the pros and cons/risk of such a chemical to the dragon.

What kind of organs would need to be developed or changed to achieve this?

Maybe the dragon teeth could be retracted so the teeth won't get knocked out.
Similar to [Toothless](https://howtotrainyourdragon.fandom.com/wiki/Toothless_(Franchise)) from [How to Train your Dragon](https://www.dreamworks.com/how-to-train-your-dragon)

[image]

I'm also considering shark teeth like growth, so if retracting the teeth is impossible biologically, at least the teeth can be knocked into the other sharp shrapnel with the gizzard stones without fear of really becoming Toothless.

Or should I use the tongue like a cannon to spew or breath the explosive instead?

Or should I use a mouth shaped like a cannon or a seahorse mouth instead? If I need to modify the mouth, please also provide a likely food source or a way for them to eat. (They are pure carnivores by the way.)

Comment: It has been years since I've seen a concept of dragons that made me say "hey that's awesome!" I wish we could award bounties to questions!

Answer (score 4):

Such explosive shells are made, naturally enough, by shell glands.  A peculiarity of evolution has caused the dragon to grow blind-ended oviducts in its larynx, which produce lumps of albumen that are then wrapped up in a hardened shell.

However, in this particular instance, the "albumen" is actually a collection of vesicles of ammonium nitrite (note the "i" - less stable).  These are produced by pumping the two ions, ammonium and nitrite, into vesicles where they then precipitate at high concentration.  The nitrite is produced by symbiotic intestinal bacteria; unfortunately, it means that dragon meat must formally be marked "Processed Meat" at the supermarket, even when fresh.  But the oviducts remove it avidly from the blood, keeping the concentration relatively low in most tissues..  The vesicles accumulate at the tips of the cells of the upper oviducts which are lost by apocrine secretion.

Also the "shell" is much thicker.  Perhaps it is only calcium, perhaps with protein filaments that help it to shatter in a jagged manner.  This evolution - for shrapnel - has not been tested on Earth.

Residual cytoplasm of the secretory cells is able to respond to cues from the dragon, "arming" the vesicles by changing their pH (more acid, if I recall) to destabilize the nitrite.  This process should be reversed quickly if they are not used.  The instability should be such that a strong shock, transmitted via the shattering calcium shell, creates points of pressure sufficient to set off the vesicles ... of course, it is vital that they not be any more unstable than this!

Comment: This is certainly the better answer, but I think the OP somehow wants a biological cannon. Also have some concern for self-detonating eggs internally exploding on a rough landing. Perhaps "laying" explosive eggs, carrying them in a specially armored external pouch (blasts directed away from body claymore-style) with a prehensile tail used like a catapult? Less cannon, more "hand" grenades.

Comment: Hmmm.  In "explosive mix with shrapnel" I thought he wanted a spray of small projectiles each of which contained explosives and would detonate on contact.  But you may well be right the way you read it.  But if all he needs is a *cannon* ... well, I can't fit it in this space.

Comment: I am going a slight frame-shift route on my answer, but I'm referencing you on the explosives. +1

Comment: Oh, about the landing: remember, before release the eggs contain bits of cellular cytoplasm around the vesicles that maintain their pH in the alkaline range, where the nitrite is more stable.  Only when the dragon gives the eggs some signal (perhaps a warning shake with a characteristic frequency) do they temporarily arm for explosion.

Comment: @DWKraus my question is about biological shotgun not cannon.

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible for your dragon to pick up pebbles, which it stores in a small pouch near its throat. When it needs to attack, the pouch will contract and bring the pebbles to the back of its mouth. Muscles in the throat will block of the oesophagus and the nose, so that when the dragon forcefully exhales, the air from its lungs forces out the pebbles in an explosive manner. Surprisingly, most species can already do something similar, even humans. We call it...coughing.

Comment: uhh...i mean not from pressure kind of force, hence "hot water jet" , but through explosvie chemical reaction.

but apreciate nonetheless

Comment: @LiJun: The problem with explosions is that they go both ways...

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: @LiJun: If the explosion projects a mass of 1kg at 10 m/s forward, it must also project a momentum of 10 kgm/s backwards. That means if your dragon uses a projectile attack on something in front of it, it must absorb the same amount of damage _inside_ its mouth. Now, consider what it means to fight another dragon...if it manages a hit strong enough to knock its opponent back, it must take the same hit near vulnerable innards; the other dragon at least has armour protecting it. You get the most peaceful dragon species in the world, as the ones with a habit of striking first wipe themselves out.

Comment: what if the organs have shock resistance or absorbance? since i assume the flying shrapnel (which i assume wont flow backward like canon ball although spread out) is more lethal than the force of explosion itself.

Comment: @LiJun: The primary reason any animal has weapons is to beat off competitors, usually their own species. It's pointless to get into an arms race with predators; far more efficient to just run away. A dragon's weapons must therefore be capable of harming dragons. Now, in the case of fire, the damage is done by the heat, not the impact of the relatively tiny amount of mass. In this case, though, you are using the momentum of a projectile to cause the damage, therefore, there must be an equal and opposite impact to your dragon as momentum is conserved. It doesn't matter whether the projectiles...

Comment: ...are shrapnel or ball-bearings, the damage is done by the momentum of the projectile being transferred to the target. Again, by conservation of momentum, your dragon is receiving an equal amount of momentum being transferred to it, and this is the important part, _inside_ its armoured hide. If your dragon wants explosive force to drive a projectile, it needs to buy a gun like everyone else. That way, the damage is to the inside of a metal barrel, not the inside of a squishy body.

Comment: >"If the explosion projects a mass of 1kg at 10 m/s forward, it must also project a momentum of 10 kgm/s backwards": This is usually not a problem, as kinetic energy is quadratic and momentum is linear, that is: most of the energy goes in the projectile and not in the gun.

Comment: You could imagine a  bone structure strong enough to not receive dommage from some explosive type, you could even imagine some projectile (birds are able to produce one egg every  day or so, so same calcium could produce projectils). However making all to work together in an efficient way does not seems evident.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: Guns firing comparatively tiny bullets still kick enough to bruise your shoulder. The pebble, in this case, must be fired at a high enough speed to penetrate dragon scales, so the dragon equivalent of small arms for humans. Now imagine having to absorb a pistol's kick in your throat. Most of it will be air pressure, you can't use bone to block it without losing off the dragon's throat altogether, which inhibits the mouth's primary function. Moveable bone pates will not be airtight, flesh is needed to from a vacuum seal, which will be vulnerable to high pressure air

Comment: @nzaman: Not necessarily: 1) Old guns were charged from the exhaust side, that is, no need for flesh sealing. 2) Also, `Vf=a*t` this mean that a longer acceleration "pipe" allows for a softer detonation/deflagration with same output speed (which additionally has better energetic efficiency).
3) More, airtight is not required: if you already built some gun or blowpipe, you will find that some airflow around the "bullet" or back has little impact. 4) Finally, there are non-return valves with no moving part, which could be done with fully rigid bones (tesla valve).

Comment: @AdrianMaire: Gun bullets tend to have their own propellant. The answer above refers to pebbles, propelled through air pressure from the dragon's lungs, so a closer approximation would be your example of a blowgun. Bear in mind, from the OP, we are talking a shotgun configuration, and what I suggested was coughing as a means of generating force. The stones will be propelled from the back of the throat and the reaction will make its way back down. F=m*a. Non return valves would reduce the forward directionality, thus reducing the range and force

Answer (score 1):

### Sabot Rounds:

I think you can come up with a variety of biochemical explosives; these have been addressed many times in numerous variants in worldbuilding. But I think you need to address the larger problems with your technique, and come up with a solution to your dragon-on-dragon fighting.

First, internal explosions are very challenging for organic life. Lots of our parts are soft, mushy, and prone to tearing, crushing, and shock effects. I think that you can compensate for most of these with a tough, bone/shell tube with lots of muscle, but that barrel will still be  rather elastic (to deal with recoil and shock) and tend to absorb much of the force of the blast. So your projectiles will tend to be underpowered.

Second, you are fighting dragons, who have presumably evolved to deal with this kind of attack. The likely have various layers of composite sandwiching to absorb shrapnel and relatively low-velocity piercing attacks. In other words, what they can't dodge probably can't penetrate.

What you need is a [sabot round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabot_(firearms)). Your dragon needs to apply more force to a small projectile than what an average dragon throat will probably be able to manage. Further, most tiny, armor-piercing aerodynamic projectiles won't conveniently fire out of a large cannon-barrel/dragon throat - the shape would be wrong.

So your dragon manages a relatively large but low pressure explosion using whatever flammable gas they can muster for a dragon breath. But the dragon has laid an internal egg. This can be a hard shell/calcium carbonate spike, or perhaps something heavy and thin it has swallowed and built up a pearly coating on like a clam (this might explain dragons attacking knights - they want to swallow swords and dense sharp metals).

The egg creates a sabot around the projectile, so the gasses are trapped and efficiently propel the missile out of whatever orifice the dragon is firing. The shell flies apart as soon as it leaves the dragon, and the small armor piercing projectile has lots of kinetic energy and possibly even aerodynamics to penetrate it's armored foe.

- As an alternative to the sabot design, an egg similar to what Mike Serfas was proposing could be internally manufactured but then laid and carried in a special armored pocket on the dragon. Accidental detonations would be carried away like a shaped charge or claymore. The dragon could use a prehensile tail to hurl these projectiles at their enemies, allowing the explosives to be safer for the thrower and not requiring so much internal modification of the dragon to work.

[image: sabot][image]

[image: projectile]

Comment: actually no, this was not to use against other dragon, that was nzaman own assumption/logic you can check previous edit to see yourself if you dont believe me,  they have teeth and claws specifically to deal with each other afterall, just like how dragon are usually immune to their fire breath, or komodo dragon or other poisonous reptile deal with each other, since they are obviously immune to their own poison which is their best weapon to get prey.

Comment: otherwise thanks, your answer did give me some inspiration how i should shape or form the "barrel". just to be clear though i want a shotgun rather than cannon as much as the chemical part getting shrug off.